# Virtuemart Multi image upload not adding images

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I wanted to put this here for anyone with a similar issue, Virtuemart Multi Image Uploader doesn't save images to the product. This is caused by a new table column called 'has_medias'

Comment: Why aren't you posting your Joomla content at Joomla Stack Exchange? Can you perhaps paint a more details scenario where this issue occurs?

Comment: Might I ask what version causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

/plugins/system/virtuemart_multiupload/ajax/process.php

```
    // New query to update VM Medias table
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->update('#__virtuemart_products')
        ->set('has_medias = 1')
        ->where('virtuemart_product_id = ' . (int) $virtuemart_product_id);

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->execute();

    if ($db->getErrorNum())
    {
        $json['error'] = JText::sprintf('Error setting has_medias on #__virtuemart_virtuemart_products', $db->getErrorNum(), $db->getErrorMsg()).'<br />';
        return false;
    }
    // End new Query
```

Below the previous _media insert query to resolve the issue.

Comment: Never give `$db->getErrorNum()` or `$db->getErrorMsg()` strings to the end user in production.  To check if an update query was successful, check the affected rows.

Comment: What does the original code look like? How does your edit affect the behavior? Why does your solution work?

Comment: This is mainly just an FYI for others. The above code needs to be added. To the end of the main function with query updates. VM adds in a new has_medias column and therefor on new products the multi-added images are not shown until has_media is set to 1.

Comment: I get it, but I am encouraging you to edit your posts (not necessarily reply to me in comments).

Comment: Here's an alternative, single method call which should do the same thing.  https://3v4l.org/3M2DB  If you wish, you may add it to your answer-- I don't intend to post an answer.

Comment: That's true, but not compaitble with older PHP versions, the above just uses the native functions within the plugin.

Comment: What deprecated version of php/joomla do you want to support?